# FireBase Auth SignOut : PlatformException(FirebaseException, User has already been linked to the given provider., null)

Tags: firebase, authentication, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am doing firebase authentication for user.I login with google and phone simultaneously.The user is authenticated successfully and signed in like that.

[image]

but when i signOut from the app,and try to sign in again with the same google and phone it tells me -

> Failed to verify SMS code: PlatformException(FirebaseException, User
>   has already been linked to the given provider., null)

I have used the following code to signout from the app.

```
FlatButton(
              child: Text("Sign out", style: theme.textTheme.button),
              onPressed: () async {
                await GoogleSignIn().signOut();             
                await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();

              },
            )
```

Comment: But what if someone uninstalled the app and reinstalled. The answer below doesnt work with it. plz help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this problem is solved by deleting the firebase user from the firebase auth console.

Hopefully,I had data linked to that account in the firestore database which I used to again authenticate that user when he tries to login after some gap and retrieving his previous data with searching the key(phone Number).

```
final FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser;
 onPressed: () async {
                await GoogleSignIn().signOut();
                googleUser.clearAuthCache();
                print('SignedOut');
                await firebaseUser.delete();
                await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();                
                print('signedOut from FireBase');                
              }
```

This issue got solved without any prone damage to data linked with the User.